# Properly using QT wrappers to upload 3D texture

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, opengl

I'm trying to upload a texture from a OpenCV 3D matrix using the QT wrappers.

This is my code (including tests):

```
 unsigned char * buffer = new unsigned char[m_vol_data.total()];
    for (int i = 0; i < m_vol_data.size[0]; i ++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m_vol_data.size[1]; j ++)
            for (int k= 0; k < m_vol_data.size[2]; k ++)
            {
                buffer[i + m_vol_data.size[0] * (j + m_vol_data.size[2] * k)] = m_vol_data.at<uint8_t>(i, j, k);
//                      printf("%d, %d \n", m_vol_data.at<uint8_t>(i, j, k),buffer[i + m_vol_data.size[0] * (j + m_vol_data.size[2] * k)]);
            }

    m_texture = new QOpenGLTexture(QOpenGLTexture::Target3D);
    m_texture->setSize(m_vol_data.size[0], m_vol_data.size[1], m_vol_data.size[2]);
    m_texture->allocateStorage(QOpenGLTexture::Luminance, QOpenGLTexture::UInt8);
    m_texture->setData(QOpenGLTexture::Luminance, QOpenGLTexture::UInt8, buffer);
    m_vol_uploaded = true;

    unsigned char * check = new unsigned char[m_vol_data.total()];
    glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, check);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        printf("%d\n", check[i]);
    std::cout << m_vol_data.total() << std::endl;
```

The first (commented) print shows me what I expected, all values being 255 (dummy test). However, my cube is appearing all black in the screen. The second print shows unexpected values, ranging from 0 to 255.

These are the shaders:

```
  m_program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, "#version 410 core\n"
                                                            "in vec4 vPosition;\n"
                                                            "uniform mat4 pMatrix;\n"
                                                            "uniform mat4 mvMatrix;\n"
                                                            "smooth out vec3 uv;\n"
                                                            "void main() {\n"
                                                            "   gl_Position = pMatrix * mvMatrix * vPosition;\n"
                                                            "   uv = (vPosition.xyz + vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0))/2.0;\n"
                                                            "}");
  m_program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, "#version 410 core\n"
                                                              "in vec3 uv;\n"
                                                              "uniform sampler3D tex;\n"
                                                              "out vec4 fragColor;\n"
                                                              "void main(){\n"
                                                              "  vec3 color = texture(tex, uv).rrr;\n"
                                                              "  fragColor.rgb = color;\n"
                                                              "};");
```

I'm trying to figure it out the problem, with no success. Any clue wold be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create and fill a `QOpenGLTexture` object, however the OpenGL pipeline does not actually start using that object unless you bind it to a unit ready for rendering. You should call it either as `m_texture->bind()` or `m_texture->bind(uint unit)`, depending on your renderable object.

The second print outputs garbage values, because the following line tries to read from an empty texture, into an `unsigned char` array of size `m_vol_data.total()`.

```
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, check);
```

More documentation about the class is [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopengltexture.html).